# Generate a vector of sequence greater than 1 but less than n in r

Tags: r

How do I generate a vector of sequence in this range `1<i<n` that is the number contained in the vector will be a positive integer greater than 1, but less than n.
Here is what I tried bellow:

```
n <- 10
my_seq <- seq(from => 1, to =< n)
```

It gave me this error:

```
Error: unexpected '>' in "my_seq <- seq(from =>"
```

**my expected output should be**

```
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: `1:n` or `seq(1, n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which type of vectors you need. Below are some examples:

- If you want to have ascend sequence (without duplicates)

```
seq(n-2)+1
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

- If you want to shuffle the values `2` to `n-2`:

```
sample(n-2)+1
# [1]  6  7  9  5  8  4  2  3
```

- If you need random integers that allow duplicates

```
sample(n-2,replace = TRUE)+1
# [1]  5  2  8  9  4  3  6  9
```

Comment: do you mean there is no way to use `<` or `>` sign in `seq()` function?

Comment: @DanielJames I don't think you can use inequalities in `seq()`

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the sequence using

```
n <- 10
2:(n-1)
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

OR

```
seq(2, n - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
tail(head(1:n, -1), -1)

[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```